# 1995 GM OBD transitional 1.5 scan tool

Tags: obd

I have had a 1995 Pontiac SSEi for 2 years without a code reader but now want to buy one. From the previous discussions I have read, there seems to be no available and affordable scan tool.
Has anyone found anything recently, for instance on Amazon or Ebay, that works?

Comment: Define affordable, a used Solus or MT2500 is relatively cheap.

Comment: This seems to be a shopping question ... is there an actual issue you're having with your SSEi you'd like help with?

Comment: I have a check engine light that comes on when idling after about 15 minutes of driving. As soon as I accelerate the light goes off.

Comment: Thanks Ben. The MT2500 for around $200 is affordable. I guess my concern is that it will definitely work for my vehicle and if not, can it be returned. I have read so many comments by people who buy a scanner that does not work for them.